# Replace a string with HTML

Tags: php, str-replace, dompdf

I'm using `str_replace` as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/php">
        $new_str = str_replace( '[[str_to_replace]]' , $GLOBALS['html'] , $original_str );
    </script>

    <div class="wrapper">[[str_to_replace]]</div>

    <?php 

    // multiple includes

    // lots and lots of code

    //PHP code to calculate HTML code
    //value of $html depends on data calculated after div.wrapper is drawn
    $GLOBALS['html'] = '<input type="text" />';
    ?>    

    </body>
</html>
```

I'm forced to wrap the PHP code in a `script` tag because the document is getting passed to a library as an HTML document. The library has the ability to execute PHP code inside script tags but in this case is working oddly.

What I'm expecting:

`[[str_to_replace]]` should become an HTML input field.

What I'm getting:

`[[str_to_replace]]` becomes the literal string `<input type="text" />`.

How do I get the second result?

Comment: How are you outputting the string on the page? If it is being processed further by something like php's `htmlentities` or Drupal's `check_plain` then it's being escaped again.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be `&` when you've passed in `&amp;`? Do you mean that the text on the HTML page looks like `&amp;`

Comment: @Aiias I've updated my question - I'm using it an unusual circumstance, that I was hoping wasn't connected.

Comment: @NicholasPickering - If the `&`s are already being escaped into `&amp;`, are you sure you need a `str_replace()` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I need `str_replace`. I have a template file, I want to replace a template section with generated HTML - but instead it's showing the encoded HTML.

Comment: I believe this may be a problem with the lib you are using. If you do a `str_replace` as '&' instead of '&amp;' then in (standard) PHP it simply works as expect (you get '&'). The extra 'amp;' will appear if you warp in `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: @NicholasPickering - And if you remove the `str_replace()`, do you get your desired output?

Comment: @Aiias No, If I remove the call to `str_replace` my template section gets left untouched. See my updated question details.

Comment: @NicholasPickering - Shouldn't you be outputting `$new_str` in `<div class="wrapper"></div>`?

Comment: @Aiias No, I can't do that because the value of $new_str is dependent on data that is calculated after `div.wrapper` is drawn.

Comment: @NicholasPickering - I'm not sure exactly what your question is then. If `$original_str = 'test one two test three test';` and you run `$new_str = str_replace('test', '&', $original_str)`, under normal circumstances in php, `$new_str` will be `'& one two & three &'`

Comment: @Aiias I've probably abstracted the problem too far - the `$original_str` in this case is the contents of the HTML document itself. I extremely appreciate the help by the way.

Comment: @NicholasPickering - Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26347/discussion-between-aiias-and-nicholas-pickering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely misinterpreting wht you can do with inline script. In dompdf HTML is parsed separately from inline script. Any HTML you insert into the document using inline script will be treated as plain text. What you should be doing is parsing your document first then passing the results to dompdf.

FYI, It's hard to see from your sample exactly what you're doing in the code. Plus we can't see what's going on with dompdf. I'm having a hard time seeing how everything ties together.

Comment: Thats about what it came down to in my discussion with Aiias. I tried to strip my code down to the most basic elements of the problem. Turns out I'm not able to modify the DOM after the HTML document has been passed. Had to handle my changes before that. In dompdf, you can only access certain information from within the inline script... so you aren't able to modify the DOM based on information from 'inline script only' data.

Comment: That about sums it up. Inline script is mostly good for adding content. It's not entirely impossible to modify the document content, but it's a lot more trouble than it's worth in most situations.

Comment: __Any HTML you insert into the document using inline script will be treated as plain text.__ This was the information I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is to replace the string with decoded HTML entities. You'll probably want to do:

```
$htmlEntityString = '&amp;'; // String containing HTML entities that you want to decode.
$new_str = str_replace( '[[str_to_replace]]' , html_entity_decode($htmlEntityString) , $original_str );
```

In this case, whatever HTML you have with HTML entity form will be decoded and will replace the substring.

Read more about it for all the options:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: wrapping the string in `html_entity_decode` didn't effect it. It must be getting encoded somewhere further down the line.

Comment: This is equivalent to `$new_str = str_replace('[[str_to_replace]]', '&', $original_str);`.